# Difference in numpy matrices gives absurd results

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy int matrices a and b, if I create `diff = a-b` than something weird happens... I have huge values that weren't present in any of the 2 matrices.
In the picture you can see that the max value of a and b is 52, there are no nan values, but the value diff[0][8] (and many other but not all) is 4294967295.
[Screen shots of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPNHz.png)

Any guess?

Comment: You're using unsigned ints. When you a>b, a-b can't be negative so it wraps around.

Comment: Please **do not post links to code or especially not images of code**. Your question should provide a [mcve] in *the question itself as formatted text*. Please see [ask] and the [help]. I *suspect* this is the result of integer overflow, but without a [mcve] we can only speculate

Comment: @erip thanks! change type to float works :)